# Some problem with regex

Tags: php, regex

hello all in my site users can insert data using tabular format. that table can be of any style. but im using regex to give those tables a standard format of our site.but when im using regex it works well but it is removing colspan. but i need colspan widout it tables looks very odd.
will anyone please tell me wats wrong with my regex??
following is my regex codes:

```
$table=eregi_replace("<table[^>]*>","<table  width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='tabularData'>", $table);
$table= preg_replace('/style\s*=\s*(\'|").+(\'|")/i', '', $table);
$table= preg_replace('/bgcolor\s*=\s*(\'|").+(\'|")/i', '', $table);
$table=eregi_replace("<span[^>]*>","",$table);
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: ereg functions are deprecated.

Comment: And mixing ereg and preg functions together is even more ew.

Comment: And using Regexes to parse HTML is even more ewww. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily style the tables with Javascript. In fact you should. Having a regex run like that over users code can lead to security problems if the user figures out your regex (and if you fail to implement it properly; which will probably be the case).

```
// jquery table styling example (picks up all tables)
$('table').css({
    'width': '100%',
    'background-color': '#F00'
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not just security problems. The code will likely have bugs and be hell to maintain

Comment: @Sam Thanks! with would be a nice if/else feature to have in CSS, though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions where is no need do to that.
Use [DOM](http://lv.php.net/dom) to parse this.